# Importing very large C projects in CLion. (200k+ headers)

Tags: clion

I want to start using CLion at work instead of Eclipse (Eclipse needs 4h+ to index my project and use 9GB RAM).
As I mentioned in the title the project is very large and has two subprojects. So what I have done was put all projects in the same folder and done an "Import project from source". The CMakeLists.txt is made automatically by CLion and has a size of 44MB.

Now my problem is that CLion does not find any definition of anything in the project. (Need to mention that the project use a private toolchain).

Can anyone help me set the CLion environment?

Comment: Please, remove [intellij-idea] tag. It is CLion IDE problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you need at least one standard toolchain to extract the compiler options from `CMake` project. It can be a fake target, but it need to exist for right source parsing procedure.